# Remove data from Object using its value property

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've been trying remove an item from an object so that it will not be included in my options to be displayed.
This is the data that I have when I console.log it.

```
method = [{"name":"Test1","value":"test1","status":1},{"name":"Test 2","value":"test2","status":1}]
```

What I want is to remove the `test2` from this data. I have tried doing these:

```
var index = method.findIndex(function(o){
       return o.value === 'test2';
    });
    if (index !== -1) method.splice(index, 1);
```

And also

```
method.filter(function (el)
     {
       return el.value!=='test2';
     });
```

But they both returned either `method.filter is not a function` or `method.findIndex is not a function`. I've tried other solutions in SO but it's still not working.
How can I successfully remove `test2`?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). It is not clear what `method` is and how it is defined, but it seems to not be an Array or other iterable

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Edited for the method values.

Comment: You script works. Something else is going on

Comment: Are you missing the `module.exports` anywhere? (if it is applicable in your case)

Comment: @DavidR Unfortunately, no. it's handled.

Comment: Thank you guys! I forgot that I am using SSM and data is saved as String. Have to JSON.parse to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach

```
method.map( (singleObject,i) => {
    if(singleObject.value == 'test2') {
        delete method[i].value
    }
})
```

it will del only first key-value pair which includes ('test2')..

but this method will delete all the values having 'test2'

```
method.map( (singleObject,i) => {
    Object.entries(singleObject).map( (key) => {
        if(key[1] == 'test2'){
            delete method[i][key[0]]
        }
    })
})
```